# PART TWO: Poisson counting process, probability system errors divided in time periods at a certain rate

Tags: probability-distributions

I've been trying to apply the same knowledge from a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282651/poisson-counting-process-probability-system-errors-divided-in-time-periods-at-a/1282817#1282817), but perhaps my reasoning is wrong.

**"Errors in a computer surfaces according to a Poisson process with rate 0.4 per day. If there has surfaced three errors during 15 days, what is then the probability of one error surfacing the first 5 days?"**

*my solution thus far:*

\begin{align*}
P  &= P (X(5)=1 \;\;  \cap \;\;  X(15) - X(10) = 2) \\
   &= P (X(5)=1) \cdot P(X(15) - X(5) = 2)  \;\; \;\; \text{by independent increments} \\
&= P (X(5)=1) \cdot P(X(10) = 2) \\
&= 3.96\%
\end{align*}

but the answer is supposed to be 44%, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the wrong probability. Using your notation, what the problem asks of you is:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X(5) = 1 \mid X(15) = 3) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X(5) = 1, X(15) = 3)}{\mathbb{P}(X(15) = 3)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X(5) - X(0) = 1, X(15) - X(5) = 2)}{\mathbb{P}(X(15) = 3)} = \ldots
$$
I believe you can finish the rest (you already computed the numerator correctly).

Comment: thank you! i did try your version but my denominator was P(X(10)=2) which would only cancel out. Your version makes more sense :)